# A monotonically nondecreasing function $ f(n) $ s.t $ f \in O(n^2) $ and $ f \notin o(n^2) $ but also $ f \in \Omega(n) $ and $ f \notin \omega(n) $

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am trying to look for an example of a monotonically non-decreasing function $ f(n) $ such that:

$ f(n) \in O(n^2) $ and $ f(n) \notin o(n^2) $ but also $ f(n) \in \Omega(n) $ and $ f(n) \notin \omega(n) $. The domain could also be all real numbers.

I considered different variations of piecewise functions, for example I considered the function $$ f(n)=
\begin{cases}
 n^{2-\frac{1}{n}} &\text{if}\, n =2k+1\\
 n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}&\text{if}\, n=2k\\
\end{cases} $$

which satisfies the growth rate conditions, but is clearly not monotonically non-decreasing.

I would be happy to hear your ideas, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that the function defined by:

$f(n) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}1 & \text{if }n=1\\2^{2^{\left\lfloor \log_2\log_2 n \right\rfloor+1}}&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$

satisfy the conditions.

To explain why, the values taken by $f(n)$ will be $1, 4, 4, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 256, 256, …$

The idea is that when $n=2^{2^k}$, then $f(n) = 2^{2^{k+1}} = n^2$, and when $n=2^{2^k}-1$, then $f(n) = 2^{2^{k}} = n +1$. That way, you will guarantee the 5 conditions: $(O(n^2) \setminus o(n^2)) \cap (\Omega(n) \setminus \omega(n))$ and increasing.